# EmbeddedDatabase using HSQL not working

Tags: database, spring

First, Im using IntelliJ (v2017.2.3), it's a Maven project with the webApp archetype and im using Spring.

I want to create a EmbeddedDatabase using HSQL, I think i setup everything properly but when i launch my app, nothing append (no errors).

This is what i have (image link):

[image: When i launch my app i get this log, so that means the scritp has been executed]

[image: So this is the DB after the launch, the DB seems to be empty..]

Here is my applicationContext.xml :

```
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="Users" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/sql/create_db.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

My goal is to execute the create_db.sql script when I start the app, the configuration seems to be good, what am I missing ?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is an in-memory database. It is only available to your application, you cannot connect to it with an external tool.

Comment: Yeah that's what i think, i'm not trying to connect to the DB with a external tool.

Comment: Yes you are... Everything NOT inside the application is external. The fact that you run both in IntelliJ doesn't change that.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean.. Then i don't understand how everything work together, when i read this : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/ it seems you can connect your app with the DB

Comment: With the database manager from HSQL started from the Spring Boot application. Not started from the outside or with another tool not started from the Spring Boot application.